# Image from polymorphic model does't display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model named Hen:

```
class Hen < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  validates :name, :description, presence: true
end
```

I added the *:picture* to whitelisted params in the HensController as well

Picture model:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

When creating new Hen, I can check that the instance is created.
In console **Hen.last.pictures** returns

*[["imageable_id", 3], ["imageable_type", "Hen"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #*

,so I assume that it is fine there.
... but I do not know how to dispay it in the view section. After some tries I have done that:

```
<p><%= @hen.pictures do |pic|  %></p>
  <%= image_tag pic.url %>
<% end %>
```

It dispays

```
#<Picture::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00005640044034f0>*
```

because I left the **"="** there (to check if there is any object inside), but the picture is not displayed. I checked some other variants like **pic.image_url** and nothing works for me. Other images on the page display without problems.
Console returns status 200:

```
Processing by HensController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hen Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "hens".* FROM "hens" WHERE "hens"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hens_controller.rb:16:in `show'
  Rendering hens/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered hens/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 5.9ms | Allocations: 3302)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 125ms (Views: 67.7ms | ActiveRecord: 10.7ms | Allocations: 36995)*
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually looping through pictures. You need to use `@hen.picutres.each` or `for picture in @hen.pictures`. Without this, you're just passing a block to `@hen.pictures`; the block gets ignored and the expression returns `@hen.pictures` (`Picture::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`).

The equivalent plain-ruby would be

```
@hen.pictures { ... this block isn't used but it's not a syntax error ... }
```

instead of

```
@hen.pictures.each { |picture| ... this block is used by the `each` method }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, now it returns an empty array **[]**

Comment: @petrov I think you also need an accepts nested attributes in the hen model(`accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true`), along with in your strong params `pictures_attributes: [:id, :imageable_id, :imageable_type, :image]`

Answer (score 0):

Here <%= @hen.pictures do |pic|%> you are printing the picture url. you should not include **=** when you are looping **<%= @hen %>** wrong you should use **<% @hen %>** then you need to loop the pictures using each.

```
<% @hen.pictures.each do |pic| %>
  <%= image_tag pic.url %>
<% end %>
```

if the picture url in hash try to convert it into string using **.to_s**

```
<%= image_tag pic.url.to_s %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the direct answer for the problem, but I found that better option is to use ActiveStorage than creating Polymorphic associations between models.

First, install the ActiveStorage:

```
rails active_storage:install
```

then add macro `has_one_attached` or `has_many_attached` to the models:

```
class Hen < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  validates :name, :description, presence: true
end
```

add to the view form:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

whitelist the `:image` attribute:

```
def hens_params
  params.require(:hen).permit(:name, :description, :image)                                                           
end
```

Done.

To dispay the image in views:

```
<%= image_tag hen.image if hen.image.attached? %>
```

No need to create new model or to nest attributes.